# Error when creating GlueSecurityConfiguration using Cloudformation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I am trying to create the glue security configuration using cloudformation script but I am getting the following error:
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/EncryptionConfiguration/S3Encryptions} does not match type {Array}]

What is the right way to give the S3encryption?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Script creates resources for GlueSecurityConfiguration
    
Resources:
  GlueSecurityConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::Glue::SecurityConfiguration
    Properties: 
      EncryptionConfiguration: 
        S3Encryptions:
            KmsKeyArn: !Ref KMSArn
            S3EncryptionMode: SSE-KMS
        JobBookmarksEncryption:
          KmsKeyArn: !Ref KMSArn
        CloudWatchEncryption:
          KmsKeyArn: !Ref KMSArn
      Name: !Sub '${SystemValue}-${SubSystemValue}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
- KmsKeyArn: !Ref KMSArn
  S3EncryptionMode: SSE-KMS
```

since S3Encryptions expects an array.